# When having a UIView scroll up with the keyboard, it seems to jump on every single textField awkwardly, not sure how to fix it

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, keyboard

Here's a gif of what's happening:

[image]

Here's the functions:

```
func getKeyboardHeight(_ notification:Notification) -> CGFloat {
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo
    let keyboardSize = userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue
    return keyboardSize.cgRectValue.height
}


func keyboardWillShow(_ notification:Notification) {
    view.frame.origin.y = -getKeyboardHeight(notification)
}

func keyboardWillHide(_ notification:Notification) {
    view.frame.origin.y = 0
}


func subscribeToKeyBoardNotifications(){
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(_:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}
```

It works perfectly on the first text input tap, however if I tap on the one below it, the view kind of "jumps" up and goes back into where it should be, which is very visually jarring.

I also tried checking if view.frame.origin.y == 0, to adjust the origin of y, but that didn't work, as the origin for the first textbox is -4, and the second is -92 (doesn't really make sense to me tbh), and I want to use this in different views and not hardcode the origin.y for each potentinal input box.

Comment: why don't you use this instead? https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

Comment: That's actually it on the screen, the grey bar. It was working fine before, but isn't since the new iOS release. Also, I'd still prefer to have the keyboard shift the view up so users can select which field if there's more than 2, rather than iterating through them in order.

Comment: Are you running any other code that sets properties of your text fields? Such as on begin editing? Setting keyboard type? Setting `.inputAccessoryView` more than once?

Comment: huh so the prolem was actually IQKeyboardManager, I guess it was doing something weird on this viewController, but it's what was causing the bounce effect when switching fields.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to add the content(only the content which needs to scroll) you wants to be scrolled up when the keyboard appears into a UIScrollView and set it's bottom constraint to BottomLayoutGuid. the get a outlet to the controller. And in storyBoard's relevant UIViewController set the 'AdjustScrollViewInsets' in AttributeInspector property to Unchecked

```
@IBOutlet weak var scrollViewBottomCons     : NSLayoutConstraint!
let scrollViewBottomConsNormalValue         : CGFloat!              = 50                    // assuming its storyboard value is 50

func keyboardWillShow(_ notification:Notification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        if scrollViewBottomCons.constant == scrollViewBottomConsNormalValue {
            self.scrollViewBottomCons.constant                      = keyboardSize.height
            self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden        = true                  // assuming its current state is true
        }
    }
}

func keyboardWillHide(_ notification:Notification) {
    if let _ = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        if scrollViewBottomCons.constant != scrollViewBottomConsRealValue {
            self.scrollViewBottomCons.constant                      = scrollViewBottomConsRealValue
            self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden        = true                  // assuming its current state is true
        }
    }
}
```